# How can I pass around state without copying an entire structure per message?

Tags: elm

I have a textbox that's extremely slow when displaying characters.

I once observed a Stackoverflow exception related to it.

I believe that the performance issue is associated to preparing the *portal* value:

```
Sources.InputAccessId _ ->
    ( { model | portal = portal }, sourceCmd )
```

Each time a character is keyed-in, I copy and modify a new portal record which consumes more memory.

The code can be found below.

**Main:**

```
onSourcesUpdated : Sources.Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
onSourcesUpdated subMsg model =
    let
        pendingPortal =
            model.portal

        provider =
            pendingPortal.provider

        profile =
            provider.profile

        source =
            pendingPortal.newSource

        ( sources, subCmd ) =
            Sources.update subMsg
                { profileId = profile.id
                , platforms = model.platforms
                , source = { source | profileId = profile.id }
                , sources = profile.sources
                }

        sourceCmd =
            Cmd.map SourcesUpdated subCmd

        pendingProvider =
            { provider | profile = { profile | sources = sources.sources } }

        portal =
            { pendingPortal | newSource = sources.source, provider = pendingProvider }
    in
        case subMsg of
            Sources.InputAccessId _ ->
                ( { model | portal = portal }, sourceCmd )
            ...
```

**Sources.elm:**

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    let
        source =
            model.source
    in
        case msg of
            InputAccessId v ->
                ( { model | source = { source | accessId = v } }, Cmd.none )
    ...
```

How can I pass around state without copying entire structures each time an event occurs?

Comment: I don't think the issue has to do with "copying entire structures," since that's not a realistic interpretation of how Elm deals with updates. I think the problem is that you're just trying to do way too much on each keypress. You may want to consider using one of the debounce packages on [package.elm-lang.org](http://package.elm-lang.org).

Comment: Thanks Chad. My app is painfully slow. Are there any books dedicated to performance patterns that I can consume?

Comment: I'm sure there are, but I can't think of any that I've personally read or could recommend

Answer (score 0):

You might want to debounce these events with libraries like this one: [elm-debounce](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/bcardiff/elm-debounce/latest/Debounce)

The consequence of debouncing though is that some events will be discarded so you only get one that sums them all when the user is done typing/interacting with the page (more precisely, after a – configurable - timeout).